# Adding a value to a textbox generated on Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

Having this:

```
echo $view['form'] -> row($form["codelist"], array(
    //widget
    "widgetArgs" => array(
        "attr" => array(
            'class' => 'input-xlarge tooltipRight', 
            'id' => "gift_codelist"
            ),
            "tooltip"=>"gift.tooltip.codelist",
            "translation_domain" =>"brand"


         ),
   "labelArgs" => array(
        "label_attr" => array(
            'class' => 'control-label', 
        )) ,"rowType"=>2
      )
  );
```

How do you add an initial value to that textbox?

Comment: That's a pretty dirty way to hand forms or aren't you using Symfony in fullstack?

Comment: @Schwierig Why do you say it is dirty? He seems to be using the php templating engine instead of the Twig one, which is a 'different' way to do but still supported.

Comment: I'm used to generate my forms in Types instead of directly in twig/php. So I normally don't encounter this huge arrays in rendering.

Sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add an actual value to the field, you can use the `value` attribute:

```
"attr" => array(
        'class' => 'input-xlarge tooltipRight', 
        'id' => "gift_codelist",
        'value' => "Your initial value"
        )
```

But if you are using HTML5 and just want to give a hint to your users, you'd better use a `placeholder`:

```
"attr" => array(
        'class' => 'input-xlarge tooltipRight', 
        'id' => "gift_codelist",
        'placeholder' => "Your initial value"
        )
```

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute